# send xml from php to flash as variable

Tags: php, javascript, flash, flashvars

I have a flash file where I can pass xml from file :

1. script type="text/javascript">
2. var flashvars = {};
3. flashvars.xmlSource = "XML.xml";
   ...
4. /script>

Can I send xml from php in varible to flash example:

$xml = "?xml version="1.0 ...";

1. script type="text/javascript">
2. var flashvars = {};
3. flashvars.xmlSource = ?php echo $xml; ?>;
   ...
4. /script>

thank you

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You'd have to change your flash file to use an xml as a string instead of an filename though.

Is there something elese to the question that we're missing? :)

Comment: but is there a way without changing flash file. Passing this xml string to flash.

Comment: You can output the xml from php and load it normally on Flash. You load the php file as if it was the xml file, and everything should work normally.

Comment: Can I convert this string to XML object and pass it to like file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like in your first example, but let XML.xml actually be a PHP file that echoes out the XML content. (Or call it xml.php and pass that as the xml filename)

Comment: so Only solution is to create new file and generate xml? There is no way to convert this string and pass it directly.

Comment: No, you don't have to create a new file.
flashvars.xmlSource = "xml.php"

and in xml.php:
echo "$xmlstuff";